# Packages installed with pip can't be imported

Tags: macos, anaconda

I pip installed 2 packages into my anaconda environment.  They are called h2o and simpledbf.

`conda list` yields:

```
# packages in environment at /Users/username/anaconda3/envs/python3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
certifi                   2018.1.18                py36_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                     <pip>
colorama                  0.3.9                     <pip>
future                    0.16.0                    <pip>
h2o                       3.18.0.5                  <pip>
idna                      2.6                       <pip>
libcxx                    4.0.1                h579ed51_0  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hebd6815_0  
libedit                   3.1                  hb4e282d_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
ncurses                   6.0                  hd04f020_2  
openssl                   1.0.2o               h26aff7b_0  
pip                       9.0.3                    py36_0  
python                    3.6.5                hc167b69_0  
readline                  7.0                  hc1231fa_4  
requests                  2.18.4                    <pip>
setuptools                39.0.1                   py36_0  
simpledbf                 0.2.6                     <pip>
sqlite                    3.22.0               h3efe00b_0  
tabulate                  0.8.2                     <pip>
tk                        8.6.7                h35a86e2_3  
urllib3                   1.22                      <pip>
wheel                     0.31.0                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.3                h0278029_2  
zlib                      1.2.11               hf3cbc9b_2
```

and my packages are listed.  When I `import h2o` or `import simpledbf` they are not found though

Comment: Please do not upload terminal output in images. See here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086

Comment: Also, how are you starting Python, and are you sure it's the right version of Python? What is the output of `which python`?

Comment: Will not post in images from now on.  I just launch anaconda by typing `spyder`.  `which python` returns `/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/pip`

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the Python executable points to pip? Nonetheless, the solution is to install Spyder into that environment, via `conda install -n python3 spyder`

Comment: Yes this worked. It also removes all of the standard packages anaconda comes with. I clearly did something wrong, but I appreciate your help

Comment: So, when you create a new environment, it doesn't come with any packages. You did nothing wrong. If you want all the default anaconda packages in your new environment, just install the `anaconda` package `conda install -n python3 anaconda`